# Difference between " %[^\n]%*c" and " %[^\n]" for consecutive scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace, c-strings, conversion-specifier

I've been trying to scanf multiple consecutive strings.

I know you have to eliminate the newline character and i've also been told that "%[^\n]%*c" is the RIGHT way.
But in my tests, "  %[^\n]" works even better because it's simpler and also doesn't go wrong if i try to feed it a newline directly, it keeps waiting a string.
So far so good.

Is there any case in which "%[^\n]%*c" is the better way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `fgets` is even better.  Much better, in fact, since `" %[^\n]"` in a `scanf` is no better than `gets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format string `" %[^\n]"`  allows to skip leading white spaces including the new line character `'\n'` stored in the input buffer by a previous call of `scanf`.

However if you will use `fgets` after a call of `scanf` with such a format string then `fgets` will read an empty string because the new line character `'\n'` will be present in the input buffer.

After a call of `scanf` with this format string `"%[^\n]%*c"` you may call `fgets` because the new line character will be removed.

Pay attention to that these format strings `"%[^\n]%*c"` and `" %[^\n]%*c"` have different effects. The first one does not allow to skip leading white space characters opposite to the second format string.

To make a call of scanf safer you should specify a length modifier as for example

```
char s[100];
scanf( " %99[^\n]", s );
```